# When to use a symfony Bundle and When to use my own code?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

1) I just want to know how to use SonataBundle ?

2) And when to use any other Bundle  , and when to create my own code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is "why reinvent the wheel?".
So why rewrite code for something that just exist?
Maybe read something about [Sonata](https://sonata-project.org/) is a good start.